# Selenium Webdriver unable to recognize richfaces dropdown value

Tags: selenium-webdriver, richfaces, dropdown

[Firepath screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bq7IG.jpg)
[Link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzsl9.jpg)

In my environment only browser that works is Chrome. However application also has issues and does not render richfaces dropdown unless browser is zoomed out to 80%.  When zoomed out, that's the only time the browser will display the dropdown value, otherwise at 100% zoom, Chrome displays a horizontal scrollbar shows in attached.  I've exhausted all my methods to try to recognize the object at runtime but it won't recognize. 
Also, the HTML is completely different when selecting dropdown vs. entire page.

syntaxes used to recognize the dropdown are as follows:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("orderCreationForm:j_id211:productSelect")).click(); //This line to click on the dropdown pulldown tree

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'Fish Hooks')]")).click();  //This line to click on the actual dropdown item
```

Comment: shared thwhtml ot link

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Using selectors with `j_id211` (for example) is very unsafe, because it's dynamically created by `Richfaces`. A new build will probably have a different selector and your tests will fail. Can you add some HTML and a screenshot for this page you're trying to test?

Comment: Stackoverflow said I couldn't attach screenshots yet due to some privilege issue, but I added it as a link above the description. please click on it so you know what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

It looks weird because most likely your CSS is overwriting some of the RichFaces styling.

As for locating the dropdown menu - it's not under the inplaceSelect parent element but under `<body>`. Most elements created by RichFaces have a unique class name (within the component subtree) that you can use to find the element - the dropdown parent has `rich-inplace-select-width-list`.